# Convergence of stopping times and limit of a right continuous process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times, levy-processes

I'm trying to prove the next:

If $X$ is cád (right continuous) and adapted process, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{Z_{n}}=X_{T}$ and $X_{T}$ is random variable.

Here $T$ is a stopping time such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Z_{n}(\omega)=T(\omega),$ where 
$$Z_{n}(\omega)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{X}{2^{n}} & if  & \frac{k-1}{2^{n}}\leq T(\omega)<\frac{k}{2^{n}},\space n=1,2,\ldots \\
             \\ \infty &  if &   T(\omega)=\infty. 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

I cannot see how the right continuos of the process works on this sequence to prove the desire limit. Also, $X_{T}$ will be random variable because is limit of random variables, isn't?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: The question seems ill-posed. $T$ is defined as a (presumably almost sure) limit of $Z_n$, yet each $Z_n$ is determined by the value of $T$.

Comment: There is a typo in the definition of $Z_n$, I suppose.

Comment: What typo @zas?